# Incorrect behavior Oozie with increased load. Hanging subsidiaries in the status "RUNNING"

Tags: hadoop, workflow, hadoop-yarn, oozie, oozie-workflow

I launch an Oozie workflow with the following structure:

```
-- Oozie workflow
------> subworkflow_1
---------- fork_1
---------- fork_2
---------- ...
---------- fork_n
------> subworkflow_2
---------- fork_1
---------- fork_2
---------- ...
---------- fork_n
```

And with a high load on the cluster, I come across a problem. one of the fork have status `"RUNNING"` but if you open this fork, then it has `"SUCCESS"` status. I get such an error even eat in every fork I read the Spark Pi.

I do not understand why the subsidiary does not convey to the parental status on time. Tell me, are there any parameters for Oozie, with which I can regulate the interval of a survey of subsidiaries to find out their status?

Parameter `oozie.validate.ForkJoin = false` does not solve my problem.